# How to mount Windows share on Linux without using passwords?

Tags: linux, windows, cifs, kerberos

I have looked at the manual of `mount.cifs` but it is a bit unclear to me which of the security methods (`ntlm`, `krb5i` etc) require password-based authentication, and which can do without.

I have a fairly simple setup -- a standalone Windows 10 workstation host, and a virtual Linux machine running on the host with Hyper-V. Both the host and the guest have me using identical *username*. I have setup the networking and can successfully mount a share on Linux like:

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.1/Users/foobar /home/foobar/windows -o username=foobar
```

On the host, `\Users` is shared as `Users`, but I only mount its child -- `foobar`, my Windows user folder. Apart from the mounted folder and its descendants being owned by `root`, which I suppose I could trivially fix using the `uid` and `gid` mount options, what bothers me most is that I have to currently type the Windows password for `foobar` to mount the share. Incidentally, my Windows and Linux passwords for `foobar` *match*, so at least I would wish for the host to forward my password transparently to mounting operation if possible.

But the best thing would be to use a form of authentication that doesn't require me to type or use password altogether. One that would also allow me to use the `multiuser` CIFS mounting option -- which could make for a really nice setup where I perhaps wouldn't have to muck about with `uid` and `gid`.

Is this feasible? Is it feasible to setup Kerberos-based authentication for this? As I mentioned, the workstation is not on a domain, and ideally I don't want one.

Comment: Kerberos would require you to setup an Active Domain.

Comment: What's "Active Domain"? Don't you mean Active Directory?

Comment: Yes;  It has been a very long week.

Comment: Have a good weekend! :-)